# Generating data for plotting function

Tags: matlab

I can plot function for example cylinder(t) by using following commands:

```
t = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
X = cylinder(4*cos(t)); 
mesh(X);
```

What I need, is to have these data in matrix `X` and then plot it by using scatter command as follow:

```
scatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),X(:,3))
```

Do you have any idea how can I do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need the three outputs of `cylinder`. Also, use `scatter3` (with column vector arguments),  not `scatter`:

```
t = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
[x y z] = cylinder(4*cos(t));
scatter3(x(:), y(:) ,z(:)); %// each argument of scatter3 should be a col vector
```

If you need the data in the form of a matrix `X`:

```
X = [x(:) y(:) z(:)];
```

and then

```
scatter3(X(:,1), X(:,2), X(:,3))
```

Comment: But what can I do to have other function, like sin(x^2 + y^2) ?

Comment: Cylinder outputs 21 equally spaced points around the circumference. The output of `cylinder` in this case will be a t x 21 x 3 array so you need to adjust accordingly. `scatter3` will not work, at least not simply, because the outputs are not 1D. `plot3` will be a shorter answer. `[X(:,:,1),X(:,:,2),X(:,:,3)] = cylinder(4*cos(t));` and `plot3(X(:,:,1),X(:,:,2),X(:,:,3))`, respectively.